# Read Write File Through Multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I want to read and write in a same file through threads.

But the condition is when the first thread finishes reading only then the other thread should write.

The solution that I proposed was:

```
class XYX {

  public void read(){
    synchronised(fileObj){
      //write the reading logic
    }
  }

  public void write(){
    synchronised(fileObj){
      //write the writing logic 
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know your ideas

I want to retain this Ordering

Reading - Writing - Reading - Writing - Reading -  so on

Comment: With this code nothing would top the second thread to write *before* the first thread finished reading.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) shared between the threads.

Since only one thread would hold the lock at any given time, you would make sure that the writing thread would only write to the file when the reading thread had released the lock (**on a finally block!**)

Comment: I agreed with you the this can be possible, But with synchronisation also we are achieving the same thing. Is not it?

Comment: What stops the reading, (or writing), thread releasing the lock,  looping round and re-acquiring the lock before the other thread?

Comment: When I answered there wasn't the cyclic restriction, so my answer would hold. This way, you'll have to create some additional boilerplate to know if a thread *can* lock the Lock (basically, if it's that thread's turn).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use something from `java.util.concurrent`. I'd suggest two `CountDownLatch`es here. Writing happens in one thread before calling `cdl1.countDown` and `cdl2.await`; the reading thread does the opposite.

Comment: Are you talking about synchronisation of threads or this kind of Ordering        Reading - Writing - Reading - Writing - Reading

Comment: I'm talking about the ordering. BTW you probably mean write-read-write-read. What would you read if you don't first write?

Comment: Yes you can take it in any way...You can say that there is something already available in the file.. I just concerned about the order...it can be either Read-write-Read-Write or Write -Read-Write-Read

Comment: Actually, CyclicBarrier is not the one to use as it makes all theads go on simultaneously. Two `CountDownLatch`es would be a better fit. The reader thread `countDown`s one and `await`s the other; the writer thread does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two semaphores one for read, one for write, with only one unit between them.  The read method waits on the read semaphore, then reads, then signals the write semaphore.  The writer waits on the write semaphore, then writes, then signals the read semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

If a total ordering of read-then-write must be maintained then it's easiest to use a monitor:

```
class XYX {

  private final Object fileObj = new Object();
  private volatile boolean writerWaits = true;

  public void read(){
    // read from file
    synchronized(fileObj){
        writerWaits = false;
        fileObj.notify(); // signal the writer to begin
    }
  }

  public void write(){
    synchronized(fileObj){
        while(writerWaits)
           fileObject.wait(); // wait for signal from reader
    }
    // write to file
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hardly the easiest way since it uses the low-level interfaces. This calls for all the usual idioms -- wait in a loop, use notifyAll and not notify... that's why we have `java.util.concurrent` synchronizers.

Comment: Don't you think writerWaits  should be volatile..just a Question

Comment: @SAM: I made it already. :) Technically if it's only changed inside the synchronization areas the implicit memory fences should ensure that the value is up to date when the lock is released.

Comment: writerWaits = false; will set this variable always as false, I think we need to make it true in the write method what do you think

Comment: @SAM: It depends if you want to execute the write again or not.